# Looking for a three state relay or switch

Tags: switches, relay, raspberry-pi

I need to control the link between three wires:

- Nothing touches == State 1 == Light is off
- Red touches brown == State 2 == Light is on
- Red touches grey == State 3 == Light blinks

A little drawing: edited by irfanview TS..

[image]

I control it through a raspberry.

I have it solved with 2 relays:
[image: ![enter image description here]

But I am wondering if there is a single electronic part that can manage this function (then save one relay?).

Any idea?

Comment: What type of "light" are you using ? If it's LED's just implement the functionality in software

Comment: it's a signal tower light: https://www.patlite.com/product/detail0000000627.html

Comment: DC or AC version? (Of the light stack.)

Comment: DC version, 24V

Comment: Your question is inadequate for logic. is it RED or BROWN (flash) with possibly both?  Next time show more info. Dont need relays to do logic, just 2 ports for 3 or 4 states  . All inputs are 0V connect to active ( open drain chip)

Comment: Perhaps you are just not familiar with the term "single-pole double throw"  or spdt relay? I think that would solve your problem.

Comment: No I think he wants three states - neither, red-brown, and red-grey.

Comment: "I need to control the link between three wires:" - what is producing the control signal?

Answer (score 1):

The [LRx-x02 Datasheet](https://www.patlite.com/product/index.php?Command=Index&method=Download&id=627&idx=5) says that for this series of stack light,

- Black is 0v, unless buzzer is present, then it's Grey (wire 9.)
- If buzzer is present, it is the Purple wire (6.)
- Yellow is +24v.
- Tying *low* (0v, 50mA max) to Red will illuminate the red lamp.
- Tying *low* (0v, current not specified) to Brown will make (all) lamps flash.

While relays could be used for this, you are correct, two relays would be needed. There is no such thing (that I've seen) of a three-position relay. The easiest solution would be to use two "open collector" transistors to pull these lines low:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f804Dx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the unit has a buzzer, then the purple wire (low) turns that on. A beefier transistor than the venerable 2N3904 would be required, as this draws more current than that transistor can supply under all conditions.

But realistically, only Q1 would be needed as you could turn on and off that GPIO to flash the lamp.

Also, for an industrial application, consider the [Controllino](https://www.controllino.com) instead of an Arduino.

Comment: Stepping relay has multiple states this one has four https://www.amazon.com/Intermatic-143RC140-Timer-Function-Stepper/dp/B007VEZKAS

Comment: Interesting... a coil, mechanical linkage, and several microswitches.  While this could function as a "multiple-state relay", isn't it more a mechanical ratcheting switch?  If it works for the reader, by all means go for it... but it is very expensive.